# How to deserialize the array of different object in c# model

Tags: c#, json.net

This is the JSON and I want to map this into the c# object using Newtonsoft.json

```
{
"PremiumStructure": [
    {
        "Level": true,
        "LevelText": "Level"
    },
    {
        "Stepped": false,
        "SteppedText": "Stepped"
    },
    {
    "DifferentPropetyNameinFuture" : false,
    "DifferentPropetyNameinFutureText" : "stringValue"
    }
    ]
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the below approach. Create a RootObj and define a property as `List` which contains `Dictionary` :

```
class MyObj
{
    public List<Dictionary<string, object>> PremiumStructure;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var text = File.ReadAllText("test.json"); // the file contains your json example

        var myObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObj>(text);

        foreach (var item in myObj.PremiumStructure)
        {
            foreach (var key in item.Keys)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Key: {key} Value: {item[key]}");
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Output :

```
Key: Level Value: True
Key: LevelText Value: Level
Key: Stepped Value: False
Key: SteppedText Value: Stepped
Key: DifferentPropetyNameinFuture Value: False
Key: DifferentPropetyNameinFutureText Value: stringValue
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) to Convert it to C# classes.

Comment: This gives me concrete generated model, but in array I may have more object for that I will have to add more concrete classes to map the model according to json2csharp. So, I want the solution which is generic for it. So  that I don't have to change the model instead of increment in objects in array.

Answer (score 0):

> This gives me concrete generated model, but in array I may have more object for that I will have to add more concrete classes to map the model according to json2csharp. So, I want the solution which is generic for it.

Then you might want to not deserialise the JSON, and just parse it to a [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) instead:

```
// Remember to add "using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;"!
JObject root = new JObject.Parse(yourJSONString);
```

And then use the indexers of `root` to access the different KVPs. e.g.

```
root["PremiumStructure"][0]["Level"]
```

Alternatively, if you want to access the properties with dot notation, deserialise the JSON into a `dynamic` variable and directly access the properties with that:

```
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
obj.PremiumStructure[0].Level
```